# Building Bochs on MacOSX Marverics

Tags: macos, gcc, configure, bochs

I am building Bochs2.3.7 on my MacOS10.9.2(Marverics) I got .tar.gz file from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/bochs/files/bochs/2.3.7/

Then, when I did

```
./configure --with-x11
```

I got following message

```
ERROR: X windows gui was selected, but X windows libraries were not found.
```

I tried

```
sh .conf.macosx
```

too but I got this message

```
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking if you are configuring for another platform... no
checking for standard CFLAGS on this platform... -fpascal-strings -fno-common -Wno-four-char-    constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Dmacintosh
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create     executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I already installed XQuartz and Xcode but I couldn't build Bochs. Does anyone know how to solve this ploblem?